# Use the '$(inherited)' flag

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I receive these errors:

> [!] The `UZApp [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-UZApp/Pods-UZApp.debug.xcconfig`. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>      - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>      - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `UZApp [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-UZApp/Pods-UZApp.release.xcconfig`. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>      - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>      - Remove the build settings from the target.

I use xcode10. They occur when I run these commands:

```
pod init
pod install
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this question.

Comment: It's unclear here what you question is. The message is quite explicit; have you done what it says?

Comment: Edit *Other Linker Flags* on the project and/or target so it says `$(inherited)`.  That is all that's required.